# ASPNETDB login page won't load

Tags: aspnetdb

having a problem with a new ASP NET app and ASPNETDB

Installed on existing server which already has a similar app which happily uses ASPNET DB for membership etc. Config etc very similar. The login page is identical to the one in the other app which works fine. App runs under NETWORK SERVICE as does the other one.

Used a nifty little app http://sourceforge.net/projects/aspnetdb/ to add the new app and the admin user to the existing ASPNETDB. Had a look at the entries in the ASPNETDB for the new app, roles,  user - all good.

App looks fine until you try to navigate to the page with the asp:Login control. Progress bar slowly grows - for hours apparently - but doesn't leave the calling page. No errors, no timeouts.

Had a look at the database Activity Monitor. Shows a process attached to the  ASPNETDB which seems to be churning continuously. Kill it and the page navigation completes but with an error about process not being available.

The other app has a similar process which only seems to fire once when navigating to the login page.

Any ideas?

Setup is Windows Server 2003 standard edition, .NET Framework   2.0.50727.3603, SQL Server 2005 Standard edition 9.00.3042.00

Thanks,
Geoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! Found it - a bug in my code. NEVER hard code a path!!!!